# WordPress plugin development- settings API vs Meta Boxes for saving data in DB

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to create a new page in admin for my WordPress plugin. What is the best way to add fields to this page and save their values? I understand that I can use Meta Boxes or  Settings API (get_option). Which is better to use for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use Settings API i.e. https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Metaboxes are for saving meta data for posts or other CPTs i.e. Custom Fields type data.

Read more about Meta here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_meta

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I add my plugin page by using aaa_register_post_type function then it is CPT isn't it? (if it is then I should use metaboxes). What am I missing here?

Comment: register_post_type is cpt but you will not add plugin settings page using it, it is used to register native CPT using native WP UI for it. Yes for CPTs we use metaboxes to add more data for each post in that as post meta.

Comment: in this article: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress-plugin-development-course-for-designers-custom-post-type/ he builds a slider plugin using the register function and metaboxes. I saw that many plugins are written this way. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Shila Using plugin, which registers CPT , and then using Metaboxes for meta data for that CPT is perfectly fine!  From your original question I was under the impression that you were referring to Plugin's setting (admin)page for that settings API is recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your Patience. I want to make sure that I understand it correctly. For plugins like: sliders, pricing tables etc. which display content to the end user, I should register CPT and use metaboxes. For plugins which their controls in the admin page are not shown to the end user, I should be using settings API (options). Am I right?

Comment: Yes sort of! I suggest you work with both and you will see what you like to use where and what fits where. Good luck!

Comment: @Shila You are welcome! You may mark this question resolved by choosing above answer.